# How can I make a boundary mesh region where one surface is defined by a 2D array of heights and the other surfaces are determined explicitly?

Tags: regions, mesh, 3d-printing

Suppose I have an array of height values such as:

```
SeedRandom[1]
heights = MeanFilter[RandomReal[{0, 9.9} + .1, {50, 50}], 5];
```

I want to make a 3D surface mesh where the top surface is defined by the array values and the other sides are flat. (Or otherwise geometrically defined.)
Ideally looking something like this:

```
plot=ListPlot3D[heights, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

but it would be ok if there was a little smoothing and it ended up looking like this:

```
ListPlot3D[heights, InterpolationOrder -> 1, Filling -> Bottom, 
 FillingStyle -> Opacity[1], Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

I've found I can export the plot as an STL file and then re-import it to get a mesh.

```
Export["test.stl", plot];
mesh = Import["test.stl"]
Head@mesh
(*MeshRegion*)
```

[image]

This seems a little inefficient.
Is there a more direct way to do this without using Listplot3D, Export, and Import?

Comment: try `DiscretizeGraphics[plot, BoxRatios -> 1]`?

Comment: There is a section: "Meshes from contours" from the [ElementMesh Generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) that is maybe useful.